# PouchDb to CouchDb replication with non server admin user authentication

Tags: authentication, couchdb, database-replication, pouchdb

I'm trying to replicate a local PouchDb database to a remote CouchDb database. Before ending the "Admin party" everything worked perfect. But when I configured the admin user I needed admin auth. So after reading A LOT I figured out how to authenticate.

```
remoteCouch = new PouchDB('http://127.0.0.1:5984/database_name', {ajax: {headers: {'Cookie': cookie}}})
PouchDB.replicate(_db, remoteCouch)
```

If I use the server admin credentials when getting the cookie then I can replicate. But what I really want is to enable a regular admin user, that has permissions on a particular DB, to replicate on that DB.

If I log in with user "X" and on the target database I have a `_security` document with user "X" on the admins list, it gives me an auth error saying I'm not a server admin.

I've read about the Replicator database en the userCtx. But when I replicate using PouchDb nothing happens on the Replicator database.

https://gist.github.com/fdmanana/832610

Is there any way I can allow replication for non-server-admin user "X"? User "X" needs your help!

Comment: how did you get the authentication info to pass to the cookie?

Answer (score 0):

I would say you have done everything right. The only thing that seems wrong is that you send the authentication cookie to the local database instead of to the remote one.

Comment: I'm testing the auth system against the local db. So that's ok.